# Only half of Wacom Intuos tablet area maps to entire screen horizontally

Tags: tablet, wacom

This happens in two different computers, one with Ubuntu 20.04 and another with 18.04.

The left 40% of the tablet maps horizontally to the entire monitor, while vertically it works fine - bottom to top in the tablet is bottom to top in the monitor. The remaining 60% of the tablet is unused. Both computers are dual boot with Windows 10 and the tablet works fine in both.

Is there a way to map the entire tablet area to the entire monitor?

I tried configuring the Wacom tablet using the settings in Ubuntu. I chose tablet absolute and relative, I clicked "map to a single monitor" in the option Map to monitor.

I tried xsetwacom in command line. Following these instructions:

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/scale-your-wacom-tablet-to-a-single-monitor/8036

I tried setting:

```
xsetwacom --get "Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos S stylus" area
0 0 15200 9500
```

If I change it to a larger horizontal value:

```
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos S stylus" area 0 0 30400 9500
```

The tablet area remains unchanged, but the pen does not go to the horizontal end of the monitor. If I change it to a smaller number (smaller than 15200) then the tablet area where the pen is "active" is reduced.

I also tried:

```
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos S stylus" MapToMonitor eDP-1
```

where eDP-1 is my monitor name from typing `xrandr`.

Thanks for any help!

**Update**

There is a weird behaviour here. If I switch on my computer with the tablet already plugged in, it works fine! If I plug in the tablet after the computer is on, the problem reported above happens.

If, when it is working fine, I disconnect the tablet and then connect again, the problem above also happens.

Comment: Are you using two monitors?

Comment: No, I have only one monitor in both computers (one is a desktop, the other a laptop).

Comment: I updated my question. I found a weird pattern.

Comment: I also get the same issue. I use two monitors, but that seems irrelevant. Only the first roughly 40% on the left works, while the vertical works flawlessly. Even mapping with an offset has no effect on the rightmost part of the tablet. No issue on Windows. It seems like a driver problem.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Hold the left-most and the right-most buttons until the LED turns off and back on.

https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Known-Issues#android-misdetect

Comment: Amazing! Perfect, not only solved the problem but also taught me about the Android/PC mode!

Comment: This fixed the issue for me as well! Weird little problem for Ubuntu users

Comment: Wow!! this worked as a charm!

Comment: Thanks for the info! I have the same problem, however, when I switch to PC mode (by holding the 2 buttons) Ubuntu then stops registering my Intuos at all. Any idea?

Comment: The vendor ID will change in `lsusb`, make sure you can still see it. Is it wired or Bluetooth? I suggest you open an issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom