# Only half my Huion h640p tablet maps to my screen

Tags: graphics-tablet

I have the same issue which is described here, but for a Huion h640p tablet instead of the wacom one:
[Only half of Wacom Intuos tablet area maps to entire screen horizontally](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255561/only-half-of-wacom-intuos-tablet-area-maps-to-entire-screen-horizontally)

The width x height of my tablet is 65534 x 32767. 
But `xsetwacom --get "<tablet ID> Area` shows 32767 x 32767, and only the left half of the tablet is mapped to the whole of my screen. The problem persists with external monitor connected and removed.

I tried resetting the area forcibly using `ResetArea` to what it should be, and half of the tablet was mapped to half of my screen; the right half the tablet and the screen were inaccessible.

My system configuration is:

- Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
- Qt Version: 5.12.8
- Kernel Version: 5.11.0-41-generic
- OS Type: 64-bit

The tablet was working fine before I made the following updates through Discover:

```
Start-Date: 2021-12-01  08:39:16
Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'
Install: linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-41-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1+1), l
inux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-41-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1+1), linux-module
s-nvidia-470-5.11.0-41-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1+1)
Upgrade: nvidia-kernel-common-470:amd64 (470.82.00-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 470.86-0ubuntu0.
20.04.1), libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu
0.20.04.2), libgs9:amd64 (9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.3, 9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.4), samba-dsdb-mod
ules:amd64 (2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), linux-
modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2+1, 5.11.0-41.45~20.0
4.1+1), samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20
.04.2), python3-samba:amd64 (2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0
.20.04.2), samba-common:amd64 (2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubunt
u0.20.04.2), ghostscript:amd64 (9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.3, 9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.4), ghostscr
ipt-x:amd64 (9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.3, 9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.4), libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.13.
14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), smbclient:amd64 (2:4.13.1
4+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), samba-common-bin:amd64 (2:
4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), libgs9-common:amd64 (9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.3, 9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.4), wget:amd64 (1.20.3-1ubuntu1, 1.20.3-1ubuntu2), teamviewer:amd64 (15.23.9, 15.24.5)
Remove: linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-40-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-40.44~20.04.2+1)
End-Date: 2021-12-01  08:43:51

Start-Date: 2021-12-04  10:46:27
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libnss3:amd64 (2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.5, 2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.6)
End-Date: 2021-12-04  10:46:28
```

Comment: Can you try booting from an older kernel in the grub menu?

Comment: Tried this, did not help the same issue persisted for all the older kernels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, update:

I had switched on Secure Boot in the UEFI menu for an unrelated reason(Win11).

I now switched it off and the tablet works without any issues.